# What determines whether a Swift 5.5 Task initializer runs on the main thread?

Tags: swift, async-await, swift5

This is sort of a follow-up to my earlier [asyncDetached falling back into main thread after MainActor call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67913756/asyncdetached-falling-back-into-main-thread-after-mainactor-call).

Here's the complete code of an iOS view controller:

```
import UIKit

func test1() {
    print("test1", Thread.isMainThread) // true
    Task {
        print("test1 task", Thread.isMainThread) // false
    }
}
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        test1()
        test2()
    }

    func test2() {
        print("test2", Thread.isMainThread) // true
        Task {
            print("test2 task", Thread.isMainThread) // true
        }
    }
}
```

The two functions `test1` and `test2` are identical, and are being called from the very same place. Yet one of them runs its Task initializer `operation:` function on a background thread, and the other runs on the main thread.

What determines this? I can only think it has to do with where the method is declared. But *what* does it have to do with where the method is declared?

Answer (score 17):

I think the rule must be that a Task initializer in a MainActor method runs on the main thread.

And all methods of a view controller are MainActor methods by default; plus, I observe that if I declare `test2` to be `nonisolated`, its Task operation runs on a background thread instead of the main thread.

My guess, then, is that this is an example of the rule that a Task initializer's operation "inherits" from its context:

- `test2` is a MainActor method; it runs on the main thread, so the Task operation "inherits" that.
- But `test1` is not marked for any special thread. `test1` *itself* runs on the main thread, because it is *called* on the main thread; but it is not *marked* to run on the main thread. Therefore its Task operation falls back to running on a background thread.

That's my theory, anyway, But I find it curious that this rule is nowhere clearly enunciated in the relevant WWDC videos.

Moreover, even `test2` is only a MainActor method in a sort of "weak" way. If it were *really* a MainActor method, you could not be able to call it from a background thread without `await`. But you can, as this version of the code shows:

```
func test1() {
    print("test1", Thread.isMainThread) // true
    Task {
        print("test1 task", Thread.isMainThread) // false
    }
}
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        test1()
        Task.detached {
            self.test2()
        }
    }

    func test2() {
        print("test2", Thread.isMainThread) // false
        Task {
            print("test2 task", Thread.isMainThread) // true
        }
    }
}
```

I find that truly weird, and I have some difficulty enunciating what rule would govern this relentless context-switching behavior, so I don't regard the matter as settled.

Comment: The ability to call `@MainActor` method `test2` despite being in a detached task is really strange. Did you ever figure out why this happens?

Comment: @Bill It's apparently a known trade-off... https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/693660

Comment: May I know, is using `Task.detached { [weak self] in` a proper way, if I want ViewController member function, able to execute Task in non-main thread? Thanks.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng `[weak self]` is irrelevant to what thread this will be. In theory, `Task.detached` should run on a non-main thread. But the way to be _certain_ that specific code runs in a non-main thread is to put that code in an Actor. That's what an actor is for.

Comment: I still not entirely clear, on how Task works with async/ await. Do you mind to provide some input on the following question? Thanks - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72001707/is-using-task-detached-a-best-practice-and-correct-approach-to-make-sure-the-ta

Comment: @CheokYanCheng So I answered that question in my previous comment. I'm not going to come over to your new question and say it _again._

Comment: It's worth noting that in swift 5.9, this is no longer the behavior and this answer's code won't even compile. once you add an await to `self.test2()` the print out is `test1 true
test1 task false
test2 true
test2 task true
`

Comment: @flopshot I think it's pretty clear that at the time I posed this question and gave this (tentative) answer, Swift concurrency was still much more incoherent than was generally acknowledged. The adoption of https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0338-clarify-execution-non-actor-async.md has, I think, been crucial. And the story isn't over. When you consider that my bug https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/57456 is not fixed until the upcoming Swift 5.10, it's a marvel that this stuff has worked at all up to now.

Comment: @matt I couldn't agree more. Context preservation is the bedrock of any structured concurrency system, just look at Kotlin, Rust, C#. All so intuitive

Answer (score 9):

This is because of how actor isolation and task creation work in swift. Actors have serial executor that processes one task at a time to synchronize mutable state. So any method that is isolated to the actor will run on the actor's executor. And when creating `Task` with `Task.init` the newly created task inherits the actor's context (isolated to the parent actor) it was created in (unless you specify a different global actor explicitly when creating task) and then processed by the actor's executor.

What's happening here is your `ViewController` class and all its methods and properties are `MainActor` isolated since `UIViewController` is `MainActor` isolated and you are inheriting from it. So your `test2` method is isolated to `MainActor` and when you are creating a task inside `test2` the new task inherits the `MainActor` context and gets executed by `MainActor` on the main thread.

But this behaves differently from your `test1` method because your `test1` method isn't isolated to `MainActor`. When you are calling `test1` from `viewDidLoad` the synchronous part of `test1` is executed on `MainActor` as part of the current task but when you are creating a new task is `test1`, since `test1` isn't isolated to `MainActor`, your new task isn't executed on it.

To have the same behavior in `test1` as `test2`, you can mark your method to be isolated to `MainActor` by applying  the `@MainActor` attribute to function definition:

```swift
@MainActor
func test1() {
    print("test1", Thread.isMainThread) // true
    Task {
        print("test1 task", Thread.isMainThread) // true
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, nice answer. So every task is running inside of an actor. That wasn't obvious. How do I get the parent actor though? Is there a way to check if it's main actor or not? Thanks for your time 

Comment: @kelin It wasn't obvious because it wasn't true — until the adoption of https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0338-clarify-execution-non-actor-async.md

Comment: @kelin not all tasks run inside of an actor, tasks created with `Task.init` inherit parent actor context, in case of no parent actor or tasks created with `Task.detached` run on global executor which runs tasks concurrently (rather than serially, which is the case for actor). It is encouraged to handle actor isolation compile time rather than check during application run.

Comment: Thanks again, it's the first time I hear about the global executor. Maybe you would recommend some book on Swift Concurrency?