# Swift - Not wait for async to return

Tags: ios, swift, async-await, structured-concurrency

I'd like to be able to let the function `doSomething()` from `class B` to not be `async` and to not block it's caller thread. But with the following code I get this error:

> Cannot pass function of type '() async -> Void' to parameter expecting synchronous function type

and xcode try to enforce the `doSomething()` function from `class B` to be an `async`

```
class A {
    func doSomething() async throws {
       //perform 
    }
}

class B {
   let a = A()
   func doSomething() {
      DispatchQueue.global().async {
        do {
           await try a.doSomething()
        } catch {
           print(error)
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can wrap the function in a [Task](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task), [Task](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Concurrency.html)

```
func doSomething() {
      Task {
        do {
           try await a.doSomething()
        } catch {
           print(error)
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: hmmm, I have this code in Swift Package and got this error `Cannot find 'Task' in scope`

Comment: ok I see, it is iOS 15+

Comment: With Xcode 13.2 it's possible to use all of the new Concurrency APIs in iOS13+. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-13_2-release-notes

Comment: But this way, await will happen on Main queue thus blocking main thread which is opposite from `DispatchQueue.global().async` goal

Comment: @mixtly87 That depends. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67954900/978300