# Is using Task.detached a best practice and correct approach, to make sure the Task is executed in non-main thread?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-concurrency

Currently, I have the following code

```
class ShopViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBAction func buy(_ sender: Any) {
        Task {
            // Will run in main thread, because ShopViewController is
            // marked as @MainActor
            let success = await Store.INSTANCE.purchase(selectedShop)
        }
    }
```

I want the `Task` executes in non-main thread, I refactor the code to the following

```
class ShopViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBAction func buy(_ sender: Any) {
        Task.detached { [weak self] in
            // Will run in non main thread.

            guard let self = self else { return }

            let success = await Store.INSTANCE.purchase(self.selectedShop)
        }
    }
```

---

Now, the `Task` runs in non-main thread.

But, I was wondering, is using `Task.detached` a best practice and correct approach, to make sure the `Task` is executed in non-main thread?

Comment: `Store.INSTANCE.purchase` is a networking I/O operation.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few considerations:

- Which actor should this `Task` use?

  Using the main actor with `Task { … }` is fine. As soon as it hits the `await` keyword, it will suspend execution on the main actor, free it to go do other stuff, and await the results from `purchase`. In fact, in practice, you are probably doing something with the `success` result (e.g. updating the UI), so you probably want to use `Task { … }` to keep it on the current actor.
- Which actor should `purchase` use?

  If `Store.INSTANCE.purchase` requires a particular actor, it would define which actor it wants to use, not the caller. It might be an `actor` type. It might be decorated with `@MainActor`. This is dictated by how `Store.INSTANCE` and `purchase` are defined. The actor used by `buy(_:)` is largely immaterial.
- Does it matter which actor `purchase` uses?

  You say that `purchase` is primarily performing network i/o. In that case, it doesn’t matter if it is on the main actor or not. If it was doing something slow and synchronous (e.g., parsing some exceptionally large responses, image processing, etc.), when maybe you would want to explicitly push those tasks off of the current actor, but otherwise it doesn’t matter.

Bottom line, the use of `Task.detached` is technically permissible, but generally would not be used in this case.