# Async task spawned inside @MainActor is run on background?

Tags: swift, async-await, concurrency

I had the assumption that async tasks inherit the actor context so if my class is marked `@MainActor` the async tasks should run on the main thread? I think my assumption might be flawed.

In my code the first `asyncTest()` method is executed on the main thread but `asyncMap()` is executed on a background thread for some reason?

Here's the playground I've tested with:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import Foundation

@MainActor
class AsyncTest {
    
    nonisolated init() {}
    
    func asyncTest() async {
        print(#function, "isMainThread:", Thread.isMainThread)
        
        let test: [String] = ["Hello", "World"]
        
        await test.asyncMap({ string in
            return string.uppercased()
        })
    }
}

extension Sequence {
    
    func asyncMap<T>(
        _ transform: (Element) async throws -> T
    ) async rethrows -> [T] {
        print(#function, "isMainThread:", Thread.isMainThread)
        
        var values = [T]()
        
        for element in self {
            try await values.append(transform(element))
        }
        
        return values
    }
}

let asyncTest = AsyncTest()
Task {
    await asyncTest.asyncTest()
}

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Which renders:

```
asyncTest() isMainThread: true
asyncMap(_:) isMainThread: false
```

Comment: `string.uppercased()` is not asynchronous or time consuming so what's the point of the example? What are you trying to do here?

Comment: @matt Yes I think I got confused with how `Task` inherits the context. Sorry `string.uppercased()` wasn't very clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `async` methods do not “inherit” the actor of their caller. The context used by `asyncMap` is dictated by the type in which it is defined (`Sequence`, which lacks a `@MainActor` qualifier) and of the function itself (which also does not have a `MainActor` qualifier). There is no reason that `asyncMap` would run on the main actor. It is not isolated to the main actor.

---

So:

- The `asyncTest` was defined inside a type that is isolated to the main actor, so `asyncTest` is also isolated to the main actor;
- The `asyncMap` was defined inside a type (or extension) that is not isolated to any particular actor, so this `async` method is not isolated to the main actor;
- The closure supplied to `asyncMap` was created inside `asyncTest`, which is isolated to the main actor, so this closure is also isolated to the main actor.

---

For what it is worth, looking at your `asyncMap` idea, it is worth noting that Apple has already provided an asynchronous rendition of [`map`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/asyncsequence/map(_:)-1q1k3), via `AsyncSequence`. To avail yourself of this, we can create an `AsyncSequence` from the array using [`async`](https://github.com/apple/swift-async-algorithms/blob/main/Sources/AsyncAlgorithms/AsyncAlgorithms.docc/Guides/Lazy.md) method in the [Swift Async Algorithms](https://github.com/apple/swift-async-algorithms) package. Once you’ve added this package to your project, you can do things like:

```swift
let test = ["Hello", "World"]
let sequence = test.async.map { await foo(with: $0) }

// and then

for await element in sequence {
    print(element)
}

// or

let result = await Array(sequence)
```

Needless to say, I have replaced `uppercased` with a call to some asynchronous method (called `foo` in my example). If I were doing something synchronous, like `uppercased`, I would just use the standard `map` and be done with it:

```swift
let result = test.map { $0.uppercased() }
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. So in order to have `asyncMap` run on main thread I need to create another version (`asyncMapOnMainThread`) and mark it with `@MainActor`?

Comment: Note that while the `asyncMap` is not run on the main actor, the code for your transform *is* on the main actor because it is defined in the closure in `asyncTest` which does “inherit” the main actor from the `AsyncTest` class. This can be seen by putting another print statement before the `return string.uppercased()`

Comment: @GeoffHackworth I think that might be due to the playground giving false results.

Comment: But if the question was "I had the assumption that async tasks inherit the actor context so if my class is marked @MainActor the async tasks should run on the main thread?" then at least that assumption is correct for the method `asyncTest`, i.e. it runs on the main thread because its class is marked `@MainActor`.

Comment: @GeoffHackworth - That’s an excellent clarification. I’ve incorporated that in my answer above.

Comment: @PeterWarbo - Yes, theoretically you can create a main actor rendition of `asyncMap`, but why you would want to? You only need this sort of asynchronous map functionality if you’re calling an asynchronous method from within the closure, so ultimately, where the work is being done is dictated by how that method is defined, not how `asyncMap` is. Besides, the goal of Swift concurrency is to allow us to suspend the current actor, freeing it to do other stuff while the async work is performed. Unnecessarily putting this work back on the main actor is somewhat antithetical to that broader goal.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use a real app (and probably even better to run it on a device) when testing these things. Also, your example obscures the key details. It will be useful to reduce your code structure to something more informative, eliminating the dross and taking the whole thing out of the playground context, which yields false results.

Try this instead:

```swift
@MainActor
class AsyncTester {
    func asyncTest() async {
        NSLog("%@", #function)
        await callMeBack {
            NSLog("%@", "callback")
        }
    }
}

func callMeBack(_ callback: () -> Void) async {
    NSLog("%@", #function)
    callback()
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let asyncTest = AsyncTester()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NSLog("%@", "start")
        Task {
            NSLog("%@", "Task")
            await asyncTest.asyncTest()
        }
    }
}
```

Here, we have eliminated the notion of `Thread`, which will basically be an error in Swift 6. But by logging with `NSLog`, we can see the actual thread number. From this we learn that both the inside of the `asyncTest` async method and the callback inside that are executed on a background thread.

The inside of the `Task {}` call closure inherits from the context, so it executes on the main thread. The interior of `asyncTest()` runs on the main thread because its class is marked as MainActor. But when we come to `callMeBack`, which is declared "in space", we are on a background thread (as discussed in my [What determines whether a Swift 5.5 Task initializer runs on the main thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67954414/what-determines-whether-a-swift-5-5-task-initializer-runs-on-the-main-thread)), and therefore the callback occurs on a background thread as well.

If we wanted to ensure that `callMeBack` runs on the main thread we would need to declare it as `@MainActor`.

As it stands, you can't talk about the actor of the callback closure itself independent of `callMeBack`, because it isn't asynchronous. If it were, you could set it as `@MainActor`, as in this variant:

```swift
@MainActor
class AsyncTester {
    func asyncTest() async {
        NSLog("%@", #function)
        await callMeBack { @MainActor in
            NSLog("%@", "callback")
        }
    }
}

func callMeBack(_ callback: () async -> Void) async {
    NSLog("%@", #function)
    await callback()
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let asyncTest = AsyncTester()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NSLog("%@", "start")
        Task {
            NSLog("%@", "Task")
            await asyncTest.asyncTest()
        }
    }
}
```

In that example, everything except `callMeBack` runs on the main thread, and you could fix that by marking `callMeBack` as `@MainActor`.

Comment: @Rob I disagree but I'll modify the phrase to turn it into a piece of general advice. (Just to give an example, the OP is not seeing the warnings about Thread. But I believe I saw some other differences too.)