What's the inverse of `MainActor.assertIsolated`?
In Swift 6, Thread.isMainThread is illegal in an async context. To prove you're "on the main thread", you now assert you're on the main actor:
MainActor.assertIsolated()

That line will crash if we're not on the main actor (in a debug build), and so your assumptions are confirmed when you don't crash.
My question is: Is there a way to assert that you're not on the main actor? If I have another actor, I can use assertIsolated() with that actor, of course; but I'm talking about the nonisolated actor, the "default" actor that the runtime supplies for situations where there is no named actor. What is the name of that actor, to which I can send assertIsolated()? Or is there any way, short of crashing, to confirm that I'm not on the main actor?

Out of curiosity, what use case do you have in mind for asserting that you're not on the main actor? nonisolated doesn't mean "isolated from any named actor", but "not isolated to any actor" — if you call a nonisolated method from the main actor, it will run on the main actor. Instead of asserting (and documenting "don't run from main actor!!"), couldn't you just have the function spawn off a detached task that's guaranteed to be run on the global actor? Or are you looking to replicate the Dispatch-style "if-on-main-queue-then-dispatch-to-global-otherwise-run-here" type of pattern?

A very common reason you want to assert you're not on the main actor is because you're planning to block the thread (perhaps by doing a lot of compute work). You wouldn't want to dispatch yet another Task when you want to assert that it has already been done. (I suspect this isn't really possible; blocking a concurrency thread for any reason at all seems verboten and there seem no affordances to help you with it. Within Swift concurrency, as far as I can tell, there is no answer to how to perform CPU-intensive work.)

@ItaiFerber While developing code, just to confirm that my code is working the way I think it does, or to discover how it is working. For instance, I'm no longer allowed to say print(Thread.isMainThread) as I used to do, so how now, without crashing, would I write the test1 method in my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67954414/what-determines-whether-a-swift-5-5-task-initializer-runs-on-the-main-thread to discover that the main code of test1 runs on the main thread but the Task code does not? To want to know if I'm running on or off the main thread is reasonable...

@ItaiFerber And what you say is not quite true: if you call a nonisolated async method from the main actor, it will not run on the main actor. I found that out by crashing! I'd prefer not to. :)

Ah, yes, if you're talking about a nonisolated async method then I you're (de facto) guaranteed that it'll run on a global actor. My bad for not picking up on that from the question!

Either way, I don't believe Swift currently offers something like this built in, but depending on what you're willing to write for testing purposes (or ship!), it should be trivially easy to wrap Thread.isMainThread (or drop down to pthreads if you want) to see what's going on.

That's the sort of thing I am experimenting with, to learn. But my main learning tool has been ripped away. So I am asking what replaces it.

If that's somehow an answer, please give it as an answer.

@RobNapier I don't believe there's official documentation on this, but for long-running work, you need to use an actor with a custom executor that executes the work off of the shared thread pool (e.g., uses its own DispatchQueue under the hood).

@RobNapier There are actually official docs for this; they're just buried in SerialExecutor. Indeed, you need to implement your own SerialExecutor which does its work off the shared thread pool, and use it from a custom actor.

@ItaiFerber While I'll accept "possible within documentation," I would like to take this example as amplification that of "no affordances to help you with it." Could such a common problem be much harder to actually make use of?

tl;dr:

If you want to know whether a nonisolated async func is running on the main actor: it never will be
If you want to know whether a nonisolated async func is running on the main thread: you'll need to wrap Thread.isMainThread/pthread_main_np in C/Objective-C/Swift to make it callable in async contexts


If you look at the implementation of MainActor.assumeIsolated(), all it's really doing is grabbing the actor's executor and checking whether the current task is running on that executor (using a low-level silgen'd function).
Given the tools available from outside of the Concurrency module, you can't implement a similar (but inverse) check yourself, but digging into the docs shows that this doesn't appear to be necessary:
Executor Types
The low-level interface for concurrency underpinning Tasks and Actors is ExecutorJobs running on Executors. Every Actor has an associated Executor that performs the actual work, and every Task is broken up into ExecutorJobs and submitted to that executor. (A job is all of the synchronous work in a task between two await statements)
The Executor protocol is bifurcated into two mutually-exclusive sub-protocols:

SerialExecutor, and
TaskExecutor

SerialExecutors are the executors defined by Actors to perform their work:

If an actor specifies an unownedExecutor, all work done on that actor will be submitted to its executor
If an actor does not specify an unownedExecutor, a default executor is provided which uses the global concurrent thread pool

nonisolated async functions, however, are not isolated to a specific actor, and thus don't use their executors; instead, they either:

Run on a preferred TaskExecutor if a preference is specified via withTaskExecutorPreference(_:isolation:operation:) (or similar), or
Run on the global concurrent executor

From the docs:

By default, without setting a task executor preference, nonisolated asynchronous functions, as well as methods declared on default actors – that is actors which do not require a specific executor – execute on Swift’s default global concurrent executor. This is an executor shared by the entire runtime to execute any work which does not have strict executor requirements.

From a much more specific doc comment in the code:
/// [ func / closure ] - /* where should it execute? */
///                               |
///                     +--------------+          +===========================+
///           +-------- | is isolated? | - yes -> | actor has unownedExecutor |
///           |         +--------------+          +===========================+
///           |                                       |                |
///           |                                      yes               no
///           |                                       |                |
///           |                                       v                v
///           |                  +=======================+    /* task executor preference? */
///           |                  | on specified executor |        |                   |
///           |                  +=======================+       yes                  no
///           |                                                   |                   |
///           |                                                   |                   v
///           |                                                   |    +==========================+
///           |                                                   |    | default (actor) executor |
///           |                                                   v    +==========================+
///           v                                     +==============================+
///  /* task executor preference? */ ---- yes ----> | on Task's preferred executor |
///           |                                     +==============================+
///           no
///           |
///           v
///  +===============================+
///  | on global concurrent executor |
///  +===============================+

Importantly:

The global concurrent executor is never going to be the main actor executor, and
All of the Task executor preference APIs take a TaskExecutor, which cannot be a specific actor's SerialExecutor, unless the executor publicly adopts both protocols or offers a way to expose itself as a task executor too

So, for a given nonisolated async function, you shouldn't need to check that you're not on the main actor, because you never will be.
Caveat
Crucially: the main actor is not the same thing as the main thread/queue, in that the main actor is guaranteed to execute on the main thread/queue, but other executors might too.

The global pool does not guarantee any thread (or dispatch queue) affinity

Theoretically, the global thread pool could include the main thread (though I don't think this can really be done safely in practice), so just checking that you're not on the main actor does not necessarily imply that you're not on the main thread.
In the general case, if you really need to check whether you're on the main thread specifically, you're going to need to wrap Thread.isMainThread/pthread_main_np in your own C/Objective-C/Swift code to bypass the unavailable-in-Swift-concurrency limitations.

@Sweeper Let me rephrase for clarity. While the main actor is guaranteed to execute on the main queue/thread, it is not the only actor which is allowed to do that — which means that checking whether you're running on the main actor is not sufficient if you want to make sure you're not on the main thread/queue (in the general case).

That cute little ascii-art flowchart diagram is more readily available to the public through the original proposal.

@matt Ah, yes! Nice find; I haven't gotten to read through many of the latest proposals.

Taking a hint from Itai Ferber's answer, I can work around the restriction by hiding the call to Thread.isMainThread behind a nonisolated(unsafe) wall:
nonisolated(unsafe) let swiftThreadReporter = MySwiftThreadReporter()
class MySwiftThreadReporter {
    func isOnMainThread() -> Bool {
        return Thread.isMainThread
    }
}

Now any code can say swiftThreadReporter.isOnMainThread() and get back the right answer. This is a good enough solution to allow me to move forward.
You probably wouldn't want to include that code in a shipping application, but I wasn't going to anyway; the goal is merely to print to learn whether I've gotten off the main thread. The caveats from Itai's answer still apply, obviously; in particular, there isn't a perfect one-to-one correspondence between the main thread and the main actor.
I still feel like Apple has a left us with a hole in the language here. If they can give us assertIsolated() they should be able to give us assertNotIsolated() (meaning, not "is nonisolated", but "is not isolated to the actor to whom this method is sent").

While I confess that I have used this trick, myself, I have grown wary of this approach (a check of Thread.isMainThread wrapped in a synchronous function). Yes, it lets us examine isMainThread without the compiler warning/error, but there are likely reasons (beyond just abstracting us away from thinking about threads) why Apple went through all the work of adding a warning if you use this property from an asynchronous context.
As far as I know, Apple has not specifically articulated their rationale for disabling this in Swift concurrency contexts, but the concern might be that one might draw incorrect conclusions and/or sacrifice some clever optimizations. The one that jumps out at me is partial tasks, whereby the compiler performs a static analysis of the code and determines whether the partial task (i.e., the code after an await) actually requires a hop back to the main task’s isolation context, and if not, it optimizes that out, entirely. It is an elegant little performance optimization, if not immediately intuitive.
In previous versions of the Swift compiler, when people were first learning Swift concurrency, and using isMainThread to validate their understanding, many were confused by some of the arcane behaviors (e.g., @MainActor closure does not seem to execute on the main thread deterministically). In recent versions of the compiler, these behaviors have been harder to reproduce, as it appears that inserting even nonisolated code in a partial task appears to reintroduce the hop that might otherwise have been optimized out. The optimization is still there if you don’t have anything in the continuation, e.g., two successive await calls to a separate context (verified by adding breakpoints and examining what thread you are on), but it appears to not happen in the face of any code in the continuation. But I would be hesitant to rely on this undocumented behavior (and might even welcome the return of the previous, admittedly aggressive, optimization).
Your point still stands, that it would be nice if there was a way to confirm that you are not on a particular actor/thread, if only for diagnostic purposes, even if we sacrificed some Swift concurrency optimizations. Especially since they’ve introduced the executor-preference logic for nonisolated async functions (which, as an aside, is one of my least favorite implementations), the ability to have these sorts of diagnostics would be useful. Something akin to GCD‘s dispatchPrecondition(condition: .notOnQueue(.main)) would be nice, but I can imagine all sorts of reasons why they might be reluctant to introduce that in Swift concurrency.
That having been said, the need for these sorts of preconditions is somewhat diminished in Swift concurrency: Back in the GCD days, the caller generally dictated what thread some code was running on, so these preconditions were fairly essential when coding defensively. But in Swift concurrency, the context is generally dictated by the called routine’s definition (with some exceptions), so it the argument for introducing more preconditions is a little less compelling.
